# How to use the concept of variable mass system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

The general equation of variable mass motion is as follows:

[image]

It's derivation is given below:
[image]

Refer wikipedia page for more details and the link of it is given below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-mass_system

**In the derivation they considered product of dm and dv to be negligible**

Check this line:
[image]

I have a question of this concept which is as below:

[image]

The answer's first part is given as:

[image]

In this answer they considered

m=m(intital)-dm ,which is equal to

m(initial)-ut

[image]

Why are they taking it like that?

The above is possible only when dm.dv is not considered negligible

check the below derivation:

[image]

So,why is it not negligible in this problem and why was it considered negligible in the derivation?

Comment: Oh,common even in the Wikipedia derivation also it is dm.(dv/dt) you just have to bring dt from L.H.S to division in R.H.S by not taking dm.dv negligible. Since you would get dm.(dv/dt) and finally also if you consider it to be negligible you get the final equation of wikipedia

Comment: Here is a similar one [(a)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/514603/238497), [(b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3440641/690654)

Comment: "Negligible", in this context, means "differential", the relevant equations being differential equations. Differential equations give you tangents, the slope (or gradient) being the respective rate of change, given by the total (or partial) differential quotient. But the rate is constant here, so the whole curve is the tangent curve; the curve here being that for $m = m₀ - μt$. Because it's constant slope, then $Δm = -μΔt$ in finite form, rather than just $dm = -μdt$ or $dm/dt = -μ$ in infinitesimal form.

Answer (score 0):

You can help your troubles with considering that the equation you don't understand:

$$m=m_0-\mu t$$

comes from the fact that

$\dfrac{dm}{dt}=-\mu\,\,$ **(EDITED)**

because of the hypothesis for the problem, the sand is spilling; so the rate of loss of mass $m$ of the sand inside the cart is negative.

Then,

$$m(t)-m_0=\int_{m_0}^{m(t)} dm=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dm}{dt}dt=-\mu\int_{0}^tdt=-\mu\,t$$

Then, you pick out an inertial frame for the observer at restwhich is studying the problem, who sees that the equation of motion for the cart-sand system has to be:

$$F=(m+M)\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\left(m_0-\mu t+M\right)\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

$\therefore \dfrac{F}{m_0-\mu t+M}=\dfrac{dv}{dt}=a$ and later on, integrate for $v$.

Note that I introduce a mass $M$ for the cart, which does not appears in the problem. This has to be done for not introducing a division by zero for the acceleration! and think about it, the whole system includes this too. You can approximate m>>M if your mount of sand is a great deal bigger, which for the problem it is (can be) done.

The derivation you include above (Wikipedia, I'm afraid) can be vague when saying that you need a product $dm\,dv$. As physicists we can use differentials as tiny increasements, but don't forget their nature as calculus quantities, which in this problem bring us to a nonsense when you worked out your solution in the sheet you included as photo. You cannot say an impulse $p_1$ has to be equal to the sum of $mv+mdv+vdm$ since you are treating functions as differentials and that is not a good way to build up a differential equation.

You have a differential equation for v, and the reason for the other terms not appearing in the equation for $a$, say $dm\,dv$ or even $v\dfrac{dm}{dt}$ is that the acceleration is just contributed by forces acting in that line of movement.

Comment: By taking F= (m)(dv/dt) and then putting m=(mo-ut+M) you basically took 'm' in the, "R.H.S of the variable mass motion equation", as total final mass but in the derivation they took it as m only I.e initial mass  why so?

Comment: The mass $M$ is constant for the cart, and the mass $m$ is spilling and therefore is not constant in time. I set $F=(m+M)(dv/dt)$ because $m=m(t)$ is obtained above and thus you don't need to add more terms like other v(dm/dt) becuase the spilling is not done in a direction towards the movement. Think about the solution for a. $a=F/(m_0-\mu t+M)$ and you have a critical point when the sand is completely gone, when $m(t*)=0$ and $t*=m_0/\mu$. From then, the acceleration of the system for all time t>t* will be $a=F/M$, where $F$ and $M$ are constant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that in the expression, (dm)(dt), each term represents an extremely small quantity. Then consider what you get if you multiply, (.0001)(.0001).